# Skip JWT Auth during Tests ASP.Net Core 3.1 Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-3.1

I a have a very simple app with one JWT authenticated controller:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class JwtController : ControllerBase
{

    public JwtController() { }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get() => Ok("Working!");
}
```

With the authentication configured as:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

During tests, i want the user to be "authenticated" all the time so that [Authorize] would be skipped.

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task JwtIsSkipped()
{
    var response = (await _Client.GetAsync("/jwt")).EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Assert.Equal("Working!", stringResponse);
}
```

Running the test like this will fail, so following [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#mock-authentication) I added this simple auth handler:

```cs
public class TestAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public const string DefaultScheme = "Test";
    public TestAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test user") };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultScheme);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, DefaultScheme);

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
```

So now my test class looks like this:

```cs
public class UnitTest : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _Factory;
    private readonly HttpClient _Client;

    public UnitTest(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _Factory = factory;
        _Client = _Factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddAuthentication(TestAuthHandler.DefaultScheme)
                        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>(
                            TestAuthHandler.DefaultScheme, options => { });
            });
        }).CreateClient();

        _Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(TestAuthHandler.DefaultScheme);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task JwtIsSkipped()
    {
        var response = (await _Client.GetAsync("/jwt")).EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Assert.Equal("Working!", stringResponse);
    }
}
```

And it still fails, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Could you try if your app ConfigureServices runs after the test ConfigureTestServices?

Comment: I just checked and ConfigureTestServices runs after ConfigureServices

Comment: Alright, then I think it should override the settings. Could you try then to add a middleware after UseAuthentication() and check if the HttpContext.User has the claims you expect?

Comment: No, and it seems like the custom HandleAuthenticateAsync is not even hit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have had a similar situation previously with the Microsoft example and can promise you it can give headaches, it may work on specific Core versions, but I have given up. I have solved this way.

My goal was, is to Authorize the system while testing, instead of using `AddAuthentication` in our test we create a `FakePolicyEvaluator` class and add it as a singleton to our test.

So let's go to our FakePolicyEvaluator class:

```
public class FakePolicyEvaluator : IPolicyEvaluator
{
    public virtual async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
    {
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
        principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
            new Claim("Permission", "CanViewPage"),
            new Claim("Manager", "yes"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "John")
        }, "FakeScheme"));
        return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(principal,
            new AuthenticationProperties(), "FakeScheme")));
    }

    public virtual async Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy,
        AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object resource)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(PolicyAuthorizationResult.Success());
    }
}
```

Then in our `ConfigureTestServices` we added `services.AddSingleton<IPolicyEvaluator, FakePolicyEvaluator>();`

So in your test code like this:

```
private readonly HttpClient _client;

public UnitTest(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
{
    _client = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IPolicyEvaluator, FakePolicyEvaluator>();
        });
    }).CreateClient();
}

[Fact]
public async Task JwtIsSkipped()
{
    var response = (await _client.GetAsync("/jwt")).EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Assert.Equal("Working!", stringResponse);
}
```

That is it. Now when you test, it will bypass authentication. I have tested it with the provided controller and it works.

It is also possible to place the fake inside the application startup, and it will be both testable for test and working under a development environment. Check the referenced article.

> Disclaimer: I have written in more depth article about this on my personal website [Reference](https://itbackyard.com/how-to-mock-authorize-attribute-for-testing-in-asp-net-core-3-1/) where you can find and download a source code from GitHub.

Comment: The Claims are missing from the ClaimsPrincipal. If you inspect the  `_httpContext.HttpContext.User` you will notice that there are no Claims included

Comment: check https://github.com/maythamfahmi/BlogExamples/issues/1

Answer (score 13):

You need to set `DefaultAuthenticateScheme`

```
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = TestAuthHandler.DefaultScheme;
        x.DefaultScheme = TestAuthHandler.DefaultScheme;
    }).AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>(
           TestAuthHandler.DefaultScheme, options => { });
});
```

Comment: yes yes this is the trick, just add another handler and set is as default in your test setup

Comment: This was the solution for me too. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

its a small change to maysam fahmi answer that HttpContext.User also have values:

```
public class FakeUserPolicyEvaluator: IPolicyEvaluator
    {
        private ClaimsIdentity _claimsIdentity;
        public virtual async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
        {
            var testScheme = "FakeScheme";
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
            _claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim("sub", "a5"),
                new Claim("client_id", "a6"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, BackmanConsts.Authorization.ClientPolicy),

            }, testScheme);
            
            principal.AddIdentity(_claimsIdentity);
            return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(principal,
                new AuthenticationProperties(), testScheme)));
        }

        public virtual async Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy,
            AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object resource)
        {
            context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(_claimsIdentity);
            return await Task.FromResult(PolicyAuthorizationResult.Success());
        }
    }
```