# Unit test Authorization filter .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am validating JWT token using authorization filters in order to check user are authorised to access the API endpoint.

It's working fine. However, I am not sure how to unit test that Authorization filter (ASP.NET Core Web API):

```
public class AuthFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    // code ......
}
```

Comment: you need to mock it

Comment: How, May I have any example please, I did google and found this https://programmium.wordpress.com/2020/04/30/unit-testing-custom-authorization-filter-in-net-core/

I am getting an error on   var httpContextMock = new Mock(); //CAN NOT CREATE AN INSTANCE OF ABSTRACT CLASS

I already have below package install
      <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.17.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />

Comment: here are couple of answer might added value for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769497/skip-jwt-auth-during-tests-asp-net-core-3-1-web-api/62166904#62166904

Answer (score 3):

To unit test your `AuthFilter` you want to test that the method, that I assume you've implemented, `OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)`, results in the expected state of the `context` given some JWT token. That is, you *have an authenticated user* represented by the token, and now you want to verify with `AuthFilter` that they're authorized or have permission to request the resource they're attempting to request. If this is not the case, please have a look at the [Microsoft .NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which explains how authorization requires authentication.

To do this, I also assume that you have some method, service or class that does this authorization check for you. If it just is a method in the `AuthFilter`, I would recommend extracting it into an interface like this:

```cs
public interface IAuthorizationChecker {
    public bool HasPermission(string token);
}
```

which you then inject into your `AuthFilter`:

```cs
public class AuthFilter : IAuthorizationFilter {
    private readonly IAuthorizationChecker _authChecker;

    public AuthFilter(IAuthorizationChecker authChecker) {
        _authChecker = authChecker;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context) {
        ...
        var token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].split(' ')[1];
        var hasAccess = _authChecker.HasPermission(token);
        if (!hasAccess) {
            filterContext.Result = new StatusCodeResult(403);
            return;
        }
        ...
    }
```

You can then create a mock implementation of this interface like so:

```cs
public class MockAuthorizationChecker : AuthorizationChecker {
    private readonly bool _hasAccess;

    public MockAuthorizationChecker(bool hasAccess) {
        _hasAccess = hasAccess;
    }

    public bool HasPermission(string token) {
        return _hasAccess;
    }
}
```

And finally, you have isolated all parts allowing you to unit test the functionality of the `OnAuthorization()` method. A simple test would be something like the following (here with NUnit, but the same applies for other frameworks):

```cs
[Test]
public async Task TestAuthorizationFilterReturnsExpected() {
    // Arrange
    var expected = 403;  // Forbidden; Or whatever you do expect here
    // This token may be valid or invalid, depending on what you expect the result from the OnAuthorization() method to be
    var token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9...";
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {token}";

    var hasAccess = false;
    var mockAuthChecker = new MockAuthorizationChecker(hasAccess);
    var authFilter = new AuthFilter(mockAuthChecker);  // Mock and inject any other dependencies that your filter might require here
    var filters = new List<IFilterMetadata> { authFilter };
    var routeData = new RouteData();  // Unused, required to create context
    var actionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();  // Unused, required to create context
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, routeData, actionDescriptor);
    var authorizationFilterContext = new AuthorizationFilterContext(actionContext, filters);
    
    // Act
    await authFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(authorizationFilterContext);

    // Assert
    var actual = authorizationFilterContext.Result as StatusCodeResult;
    Assert.That(actual, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(actual.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(expected), "Context Result");
}
```

As stated in the code example, you might have other dependencies which you need to mock to isolate the AuthFilter from the dependencies.